# Win 7 and Win 2003 Server displays ascii value differntly

Tags: character-encoding, vb6, ascii

In our Visual Basic 6.0 program we used function chr(11) appended with some string and is displayed in text box.

In Windows 2003 Server, the value in text box is displayed as "a box(for chr(11)) followed by string"
In windows 7, the value in text box is displayed as "♂(for chr(11) followed by string"

Can anyone advice why it is behaving like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a difference in fonts.

Even when the same "face name" is used the actual installed font can differ in terms of things like which glyphs are suported.

Note that your program isn't using ASCII in any sense of the word, but ANSI.  The mapping from Unicode in your program to ANSI for display varies with Locale and Charset settings as well.  Charset might also be a factor here.

`Chr(11)` says "take 11 and treat it as an ANSI character in the current codepage, convert that to Unicode, then return it as a Variant String."

`Chr$(11)` removes some of that overhead by returning a String, and `ChrW$(11)` is even cleaner, skipping the laundering through ANSI-to-Unicode conversion as well.

Faster yet is to just used the named constant for this character `vbVerticalTab` instead.

But none of that impacts *display*.  It's more a question of avoiding unnecessary overhead.

You're relying on something that isn't reliable, i.e. that non-printable characters will always have a glyph.  That "box" symbol you see means there is no glyph available for the character.

Even the Character Map applet doesn't display the glyph mapping for values below 33 (&H21).